# How an Activity can be destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity

I was reading the following article http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html aobut recreating an activity and it says that:

> There are a few scenarios in which your activity is destroyed due to normal app behavior, such as when the user presses the Back button or....

My question is: when I click back is my activity destroyed? Cuz i can still see my app in the most recent app...I don't understand

Comment: Read the Android Life Cycle, it will help you in long run.

Answer (score 3):

> when I click back is my activity destroyed?

By default, yes.

> Cuz i can still see my app in the most recent app

The recent tasks list has nothing whatsoever to do with whether or not an activity in your app is destroyed.

To draw an analogy, operating systems like Windows and Linux sometimes have a "Recent Documents" list. As the name suggests, this is a list of recently-opened documents. When you close, say, Microsoft Word, that does not get rid of the document from the "Recent Documents" list, because "Recent Documents" is not referring to running programs.

Similarly, the recent tasks list refers to apps -- not documents -- that were recently run by the user. Whether or not any activities are destroyed in a given app on that list, or if the app is even running, does not affect the list.

Comment: what about using the FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS ??

Comment: @Basbous: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question, nor how it relates to the OP's question.

Comment: if he wants to destroy the activity and not to see it in the recent, he can use the FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS

Comment: I have just tried to close an app just clicking the back button but it doesn't close it, to close it I have to turn on the recent menu app and close it..how is it?

Comment: Ok but why if I just click the back button isn't the app destroyed as it should be?

Comment: @antox: "I have just tried to close an app just clicking the back button but it doesn't close it" -- it is not supposed to. "why if I just click the back button isn't the app destroyed as it should be?" -- apps are not "destroyed". Activities and apps are not the same thing. You do not normally "close" apps in Android. The primary thing that swiping an app off the recent-tasks list does is remove the entry from the recent-tasks list.

Comment: then I can only destroy activities, can't I close an app in a way?

Comment: @antox: You're not supposed to "close an app" on Android, any more than a Web server "closes" the user's Web browser to "close" a Web app.